# Animated Underline When Hovering in Blogger

Tags: html, css, blogs, blogger

I'm new to coding, just to clear the field before asking these questions lol. I stumbled across an article where you an animate your links when hovering over them. Here's the article, http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css-sliding-underline/. I incorporated the code for the sliding middle to out into my blog, shown here;

```css
.sliding-middle-out {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.sliding-middle-out:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 height: 3px;
 width: 0px;
 background: transparent;
 transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.sliding-middle-out:hover:after {
 width: 100%;
 background: blue;
}
```

I've added this code to the "add CSS" box in blogger, and pasted this code before the  line in my HTML code, neither have worked. Help is much appreciated! #noobcoderprobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just paste the code into your template. You will need to change the selector based on your menu markup. Here is the code that I have modify. Just paste it, and you are done:

```
.PageList li a {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}
.PageList li a:hover:after {
width: 100%;
background: blue;
}
.PageList li a::after {
content: '';
display: block;
margin: auto;
height: 3px;
width: 0px;
background: transparent;
transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
```

You must paste the code into your template HTML editor, DON'T paste it inside a HTML widget.

I have test it on your site, and it works!

Comment: you are a god, I would give you my left arm if you needed it.

Comment: i'm a human just like you :P. btw, you can vote up my answer if you got it useful

Comment: I need 15 rep to vote up, once I reach that I'll come back to this post and vote up !

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for your site, using your sites markup:

```
.widget-content a:after {
    border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    width: 0;
}
.widget-content a:hover:after {
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
}
```

For this to work, you have to make the parent li position relative.

```
.widget-content li{position: relative}
```

Tested and works on your site.